# creating a horizontal list without listview winrt

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i Know editing List view item template and changing

```
<StackPanel orientation="horizontal"></StackPanel>
```

Inside the items list will create a horizontal listview. But is there any other simpler way without using listview in winRt to create a Horizontal list.

I personally want to avoid data binding thats why. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scrollviewer and a horizontal stackpanel.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="spContent" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

use the Xaml.cs file to load data from code behind. Else you can use binding if you want to.